# magento re-indexing takes too much time

Tags: magento, reindex

I have 75 K products in my store.
I uploaded 100 Products through Data Import Profile.
It re-indexes all 75 K? Because it takes a lot of time and I get error of too many connections in Mysql.

What is the solution to it?

Comment: How did you reindex? From admin panel or command line?

Comment: After uploading the products it automatically reindexs in browser. seperate window

Comment: If you go to your admin area and look for Index Management under the systems tab, have a look and see which indexes are set to "Update on Save". You can change that to manual while you do the import. My guess is as each item is imported and saved, it's making a new MySQL call and timing out, so change them to manual while you do the import, then put them back, or even better set up a cron to reindex at midnight and leave them as manual

Comment: @Shaz Try the solution suggested by PhilS it should help you.

Comment: for this you have to used Magento Partial indexing, you can go through the below link https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/free-partial-index-magento-module-ce-1-8-1-9-ee-1-12/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

you can try reindexing with ssh by running below command :

```
php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

if you want to reindex each separately ,

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
php shell/indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
php shell/indexer.php --reindex tag_summary
```

Answer (score 0):

For fast reindexing, you can login in your ssh through putty and run the below command -

```
php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for **Magento2**

First of all, reset all previously locked indexes by another process...
Run the following command from Magento2 folder

```
php -d memory_limit=56G bin/magento indexer:reset
```

Then after run

```
php -d memory_limit=56G bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

memory_limit=56G Can be replaced by  available RAM on server or By -1